# Number of items necessary to exceed a given collision probability for large spaces

Tags: algorithm, collision

(This is not a homework problem.  If there is a class that offers this question as homework, please tell me as I would love to take it.)

This is related to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

I'm looking for a practical algorithm to calculate the number of items necessary to exceed a collision probability of p for large spaces.  I need this for evaluating the suitability of hashing algorithms for storing large numbers of items.

For example, `f(365, .5)` should return `23`, the number of people needed to exceed 0.5 probability that anyone share the same birthday.

I have created a simple implementation using an exact collision probability calculation:

```py
def _items_for_p(buckets, p):
    """Return the number of items for chance of collision to exceed p."""
    logger.debug('_items_for_p($r, $r)', buckets, p)
    up = buckets
    down = 1
    while up > (down + 1):
        n = (up + down) // 2
        logger.debug('up=%r, down=%r, n=%r', up, down, n)
        if _collision_p(buckets, n) > p:
            logger.debug('Lowering up to %r', n)
            up = n
        else:
            logger.debug('Raising down to %r', n)
            down = n
    return up


def _collision_p(buckets, items):
    """Return the probability of a collision."""
    return 1 - _no_collision_p(buckets, items)


def _no_collision_p(buckets, items):
    """Return the probability of no collision."""
    logger.debug('_no_collision_p(%r, %r)', buckets, items)
    fac = math.factorial
    return fac(buckets) / ((buckets ** items) * fac(buckets - items))
```

Needless to say, this does not work for the large spaces I want to work with (2^256, 2^512, etc).

I am looking for an algorithm that can calculate this in a reasonable amount of time with reasonable accuracy.  The Wikipedia page provides mathematical approximations, but admittedly my math is a bit rusty, and I don't want to spend a lot of time investigating one approximation only to find that I cannot both generalize it and implement it quickly.

Comment: You should ask first on [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) to get a reliable formula or method that works on big sets. Btw, since this is an interesting problem, you might want to post the solution here, after.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to generalised birthday problem or probability p=0.5:

As noted by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem) there is no **proven** formula that is quick to compute, but there is a formula that is **conjectured** to be exact.  The formula involves computing square roots, natural logarithms, and basic arithmetic:

```
Sqrt(2*d*ln 2) + (3 - 2 * ln 2)/6 + (9 - 4(ln 2)^2)/(72 + Sqrt(2*d*ln 2) ) - 2 ln(2)^2/(135* d)
```

so you can feed in your d=2^256 and find out the answer that is conjectured to be exact.

Here's a quick attempt at implementing it, limited to the accuracy of python floats:

```
def solve_birthday_problem( d ):
    ln2 = math.log(2)
    term1 = (2*d*ln2)**0.5
    term2 = (3 - 2 * ln2)/6.0
    term3 = (9 - 4*(ln2)**2)/(72 + (2*d*ln2)**0.5 )
    term4 = 2*ln2**2/(135.0 * d)
    return math.ceil(term1 + term2 + term3 - term4)
```

You will need to fix it up to get an accurate precision integer result.  [The decimal library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) may be what is needed to fix this.

Comment: This does not take a `p` argument as per the question.  It assumes you're looking for `p = 0.5`.

Comment: @pjs: Correct, I only provided a solution for p = 0.5.  I said that in the post.